# Why does this script not execute scrollTo(x,y) javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hello I am trying to create a refresh script to refresh a page on incomming messages,updated posts,ect. Why is x,y not executed useing ex: 1? I have seen a few different methods of reloading a page and keeping scroll position but they seem overkill. I think I would like to use ex: 2, is there any logical way to clear the server side variables using reload() or should I go another route for something like this?

```
    function Refresh()
    {

        var x = window.pageXOffset;
        var y = window.pageYOffset;

        //ex 1:this works but doesnt keep scroll position
        //window.location = window.location.href;

        //ex 2: this works and retains x,y but doesnt refresh $_POST $_GET server side variables
        window.location.reload();

        window.location.scrollTo(x,y);
    }
    //for testing only
    setInterval('Refresh()', 5000);
```

Comment: When you call `reload` or in any other way navigate the browser window, any following javascript will not be executed

Comment: window.scrollTo(... );

Answer (score 0):

scrollTo is not executed because that line is never reached and also wrong. The moment you trigger a page load, script execution stops. Furthermore, window.location refers to the address-bar, basically, and scrollTo does not make sense here. Better would be window.scrollTo, but never mind:

A reload preserves scroll position (in most browsers) and $_GET variables, however browsers usually want user-confirmation to reload a POST-request. You probably do not want that behaviour.

The least "overkill" way to make the browser scroll to new content is using hash-tags, assuming you are in control of the updated content.
Just append something like #newcontent to your URL and set the id of your new content:

```
<div id="newcontent">Cool new post...
```

Browsers will auto-scroll to a [fragment identifier](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html#navigating-to-a-fragment-identifier).